# htaccess - only index requires valid-user

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I've got a simple htaccess set up with which I only want to protect my index.php file.
I wrote down the following which seems the most logic, but it just tells me 401 Authorization Required. If I open up the link WITH index.php, it does prompt me for a login, otherwise not.

Is there any way I can trigger that login without adding index.php to the link? I really only want the index.php protected.

```
<Files index.php>
  require valid-user
</Files>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#locationmatch):

```
<LocationMatch "(.*/|index.php)$">
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: `LocationMatch` is not allowed in a `.htaccess`, doesn't work for me.